# A Dynamicaly created LONG CAML Query Gives An Error + Sharepoint 2010 ASMX Web Services+ SQL CLR Function

Tags: sql, sharepoint-2010, clr, caml

I am using SQL clr function to call sharepoint asmx webservices.. and passing CAML query for the filter from my function..

I am creating CAML Query dynamically by my SQL UDF functions and reporting by SSRS.. but if i choose in my parameter many userID then it gives me an Error sometime...

Please find below my dynamically created caml Query and Error:

```
<Where><And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2010-10-01</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-10-24</Value></Leq></And>
    <In><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Values><Value Type="Text">adminindia</Value><Value Type="Text">adminUS</Value><Value Type="Text">superadmin</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037188</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090119</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037014</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037024</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk036993</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037725</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk040614</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090288</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037098</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038612</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037117</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037116</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk039941</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037229</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037057</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090433</Value><Value Type="Text">eqfa00064</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038395</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090120</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037277</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037000</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk040244</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk042676</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090197</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090217</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk090391</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090380</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090449</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090558</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037020</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037218</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090233</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090362</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010281</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010031</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038557</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090278</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037171</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037178</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037088</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037291</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037214</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037288</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090317</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090295</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010213</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010265</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090555</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010297</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010298</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090482</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090486</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090565</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090568</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk090571</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010264</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010263</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090375</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010196</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037313</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090014</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090251</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090379</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090276</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090277</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090286</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090367</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010269</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090447</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010312</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010313</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090561</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010303</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090231</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090440</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090257</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090265</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090266</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037160</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090005</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090338</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090340</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090348</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk090349</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090351</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037272</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090425</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090489</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037246</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037216</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090118</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037123</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037279</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037191</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038975</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090389</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090232</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090451</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090523</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090326</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090384</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010251</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037255</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038606</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk039559</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090089</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090222</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090284</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090318</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090328</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037011</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038294</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk090192</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090298</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090524</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk042354</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010291</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037106</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090117</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037119</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037087</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010215</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090196</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090227</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090247</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090263</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090275</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090345</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090363</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010254</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010260</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090421</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010292</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090461</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090521</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090539</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090538</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090540</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090564</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090560</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037070</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk039561</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090201</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090223</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090304</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090335</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090336</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010255</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090460</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090462</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010169</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010287</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010294</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010323</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010290</Value><Value Type="Text">emp1</Value><Value Type="Text">supervisor1</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037101</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037062</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037179</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090494</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037162</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090570</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010277</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010278</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010288</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010304</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010308</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090512</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090516</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk090514</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090515</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090519</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090517</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090513</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090511</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090290</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010307</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090532</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037041</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037112</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037046</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037309</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090249</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010241</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010272</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010280</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037436</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk040852</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090229</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010035</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010143</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090448</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090551</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010204</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090557</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090556</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090553</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090500</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk010250</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090501</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090381</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090534</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010270</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090542</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090402</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090403</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090344</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090406</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090488</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010296</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037074</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010072</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090479</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090480</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090481</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090483</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010223</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090484</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010253</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090485</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010262</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090269</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010267</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090471</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010286</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037270</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010302</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk090259</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010299</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010247</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090395</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090493</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090359</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010300</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090194</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010306</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090274</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010310</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090450</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090533</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090552</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010317</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010237</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010324</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010261</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010326</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010268</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010327</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010273</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010279</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010328</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090527</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk036995</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090554</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010295</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090573</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk037094</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037739</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038159</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090370</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090478</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090477</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090543</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038667</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037131</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090234</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037736</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090224</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037293</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090213</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038974</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090327</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090329</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090352</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010258</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090390</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090383</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090387</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090434</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090442</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090457</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090465</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090459</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090456</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090455</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk090492</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090475</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090473</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090476</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090474</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090468</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090411</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090537</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090536</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090541</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090575</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090572</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037308</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090562</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037302</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090503</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090520</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090454</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090202</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090285</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037257</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037114</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037142</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090209</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090279</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090297</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090378</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090429</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090407</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk010284</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090467</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010314</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090505</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090574</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk010309</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037517</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090306</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090397</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037516</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090496</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038702</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037612</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037847</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk038451</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090508</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037597</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090559</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037505</Value><Value Type="Text">equa05480</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090364</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037608</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037628</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037504</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037541</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037845</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037622</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090404</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk020926</Value>
<Value Type="Text">kkkk038495</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk014846</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037537</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090047</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037626</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037655</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090415</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090428</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090427</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090424</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090445</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037607</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk037578</Value><Value Type="Text">kkkk090444</Value><Value Type="Text">krishna</Value><Value Type="Text">ZZZZ</Value></Values>
</In></And></Where>
```

Error:

```
Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate     "fn_GetListItemsActivities": 
System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file while parsing Name has occurred. Line  1, position 4001.
System.Xml.XmlException: 
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName(Boolean isQName, Int32 startOffset, Int32&  colonPos)
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
 at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.ParsePartialContent(XmlNode parentNode, String innerxmltext,  XmlNodeType nt)
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadInnerXmlElement(XmlElement node, String innerxmltext)
 at SharePointActivities.GetActivitiesItems(SqlString url, SqlString listName, SqlString viewName, SqlString Query)
```

Please find my SQL stored Procedure where parameters coming from my SSRS Report:

```
                USE [PMTReporting]
            GO
            /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Dashboard_AgentLevelReport]    Script Date: 10/23/2013 15:03:13 ******/
            SET ANSI_NULLS ON
            GO
            SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
            GO

            ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_Dashboard_AgentLevelReport]
            @StartRecordDate DATE,
            @EndRecordDate DATE,
            @EmployeeIDs NVARCHAR(MAX)

            AS
            BEGIN

            /** Create CAML Query for start and end Record Date Parameters**/
            DECLARE @NVAR_StartCAML NVARCHAR(250)
            DECLARE @NVAR_EndCAML NVARCHAR(250)
            DECLARE @NVAR_StartEndRecordDateCAML NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @NVAR_CAMLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)


            SET @NVAR_StartCAML = '<Where><And>'
            SET @NVAR_EndCAML = '</And></Where>'

            SET @NVAR_StartEndRecordDateCAML = '<And><Geq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">' + CONVERT(CHAR(10),@StartRecordDate,126) + '</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">' + CONVERT(CHAR(10),@EndRecordDate,126) + '</Value></Leq></And>' 

            /** User Explicit CURSOR not Implicit  **/

                DECLARE @Item_Value nvarchar(max)
                DECLARE @NVAR_EmployeeIDs NVARCHAR(MAX)
                SELECT @NVAR_EmployeeIDs = '<In><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Values>'
                DECLARE EXPLICIT_CURSOR_EmployeeIDs CURSOR FOR 
                SELECT Item FROM dbo.ufnSplit(@EmployeeIDs,',');
                OPEN EXPLICIT_CURSOR_EmployeeIDs
                FETCH NEXT FROM EXPLICIT_CURSOR_EmployeeIDs into @Item_Value
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT @NVAR_EmployeeIDs = @NVAR_EmployeeIDs + '<Value Type="Text">' + @Item_Value + '</Value>'
                        FETCH NEXT FROM EXPLICIT_CURSOR_EmployeeIDs into @Item_Value
                    END
                SELECT @NVAR_EmployeeIDs = @NVAR_EmployeeIDs + '</Values></In>'

                CLOSE EXPLICIT_CURSOR_EmployeeIDs;
                DEALLOCATE EXPLICIT_CURSOR_EmployeeIDs;


            SET @NVAR_CAMLQuery = @NVAR_StartCAML + @NVAR_StartEndRecordDateCAML + @NVAR_EmployeeIDs + @NVAR_EndCAML


            insert into tbl1(camlq) values(@NVAR_CAMLQuery)

            SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_GetListItemsActivities('http://wks10953:1000/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx','Activities','',@NVAR_CAMLQuery) order by RecordDate


             /** Some Imp **/

             --SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_GetListItemsActivities('http://wks10953:1000/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx','Activities','','<Where><And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2010-01-01</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-09-01</Value></Leq></And><Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">e036993</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">e040614</Value></Eq></Or></And></Where>')

             --SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_GetListItemsActivities('http://wks10953:1000/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx','Activities','','<Where><And><And><Geq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2010-01-01</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-09-01</Value></Leq></And><In><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Values><Value Type="Text">e036993</Value><Value Type="Text">e040614</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value><Value Type="Text">e04061400</Value></Values></In></And></Where>')

             --<In><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Values><Value Type='Text'>e036993</Value><Value Type='Text'>e040614</Value></Values></In>


             --SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_GetListItemsActivities('http://wks10953:1000/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx','Activities','','<Where><And><Geq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2011-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="RecordDate" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2013-09-10T15:56:29Z</Value></Leq></And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">e036993</Value></Eq></Where>')


             --<Or><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">e036993</Value></Eq><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">e040614</Value></Eq></Or>

             --e036993
              --e040614
            END
```

.

Comment: People tried to help you bellow and you didnt even reply or gave feedback. This is a community this is not a support line.

Comment: This is done.. Actually problem was in my function query parameter i was assigned only query nvarchar(4000) .. now i have changed it to query nvarchar(max)... and now it works....... Luis i did not understand what are you trying to say ?.. I replied for everything..